# Deleting ArcMap Versions using Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, versioning

The versionName "JNMILLER" won't delete. Any idea why it's not finding the name?

Terminal:

```
================= RESTART: C:\Users\jnmiller\Desktop\test.py 
=================
Found - "EGAS\JMEESE"
Found - "EGAS\MWETZEL"
Found - SDE
Found - sde
Found - "EGAS\JNMILLER"
Found - "EGAS\SCRAWFORD"
Found - "EGAS\CCOON"
Done
>>>
```

Code:

```
# Name: DeleteVersion.py
# Description: Deletes a version

# Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set local variables
arcpy.env.workspace = "Database Connections/NEO_1.sde"
connection = arcpy.env.workspace
versionName = "JNMILLER"

# Execute DeleteVersion
for version in arcpy.da.ListVersions(connection):
    print "Found - {0}".format(version.name.split(".")[0])
    if version.name.split(".")[0] == versionName:
        arcpy.DeleteVersion_management(connection, versionName)
        print("Deleting version {0}".format(version.name))

print("Done")
```

[image]

Comment: The owner is part of the name. If you're not the owner, you'll need to include it in the name (though it might not let you delete a version you dont own)

Comment: I might be writing this incorrectly since it doesn't work but is this what you're thinking:                                                                                               
owner = "EGAS\JNMILLER"
name = 'JNMILLER'
versionUser = os.path.join(owner,".",name)

versionName = versionUser                                                                                          An error doesn't generate but it doesn't run the tool either

Comment: Backslash is a special character. You need to escape it or use raw string formatting.

Comment: Also, because the backslash is present,  the name itself contains quotes.